# Spacing- How to add gap between lines

Tags: spacing

I keep getting \hbox badness error in my code. The line(-.97,-1.37,-1.37) gets indented as well and I'm not sure how to fix it. I just want the output to have the two lines then a space then next two lines etc.

```
\section{Part 2}
(-1.03, 2.87) decodes as 0100 \\
(-3.28, -1.21) decodes as 0011 - together, 01000011 gives "C"\\

  (-0.97, -2.71) decodes as 0110\\
(2.21, -0.95) decodes as 1011 - together, 01101011 gives "k"\\
\textbf{Probable error} \\
\textbf{Probable intended bit sequence: 01101111 “o”}\\

  (-1.37, -1.48) decodes as 0111\\
(-2.86, -2.51) decodes as 0010 - together, 01110010 gives "r"\\

  (-1.37, -2.73) decodes as 0110\\
(1.22, -3.17) decodes as 1110 - together, 01101110 gives "n"\\
```

Comment: Welcome. Please offer a full MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that.

Comment: the blank line indicates a paragraph break, hence the indentation of the next line.  remove the blank lines, and instead modify the line break by adding an explicit skip: `\\[1\baselineskip]`.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me

Comment: @barbarabeeton If you don't mind bad boxes? Isn't our standard advice not to break lines this way outside special environments? What is different here?

Comment: You might put a `\begin{flushleft}... \end{flushleft}` around this part of your text. Or use a `tabular`. Then you can use `\\ ` without bad boxes and `\\[1\baselineskip]` for a 2 line skip, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Please always provide compilable code. I honestly have no idea if this will actually work in your example, as I don't know what else is going on. Shot in the dark ....

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Part 2}
\begin{flushleft}
  (-1.03, 2.87) decodes as 0100 \\
  (-3.28, -1.21) decodes as 0011 - together, 01000011 gives ``C''\\[1\baselineskip]

  (-0.97, -2.71) decodes as 0110\\
  (2.21, -0.95) decodes as 1011 - together, 01101011 gives ``k''\\
  \textbf{Probable error} \\
  \textbf{Probable intended bit sequence: 01101111 ``o''}\\[1\baselineskip]

  (-1.37, -1.48) decodes as 0111\\
  (-2.86, -2.51) decodes as 0010 - together, 01110010 gives ``r''\\[1\baselineskip]

  (-1.37, -2.73) decodes as 0110\\
  (1.22, -3.17) decodes as 1110 - together, 01101110 gives ``n''\\[1\baselineskip]
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image: shot in the dark]

Note that your original code produces only closing double quotation marks. If you want curly quotes, you need opening ones, too. If not, you need to use the appropriate `\text...` command. But in that case, you probably want some sort of code-listing markup anyway.

Comment: I think you want math mode for the coordinate pairs.

Comment: @egreg Or verbatim of some kind .... I'm not sure which would be correct here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use math mode for the coordinate pairs and `\bigskip` (or maybe just `\medskip`) between the lines you want to space out.

I also changed the hyphen into an em-dash (the hyphen should only join words) and set the bit sequences in the monospaced font for contrast.

There's also a suggested rendering with a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\newcommand{\bits}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\lparen}{(}
\newcommand{\rparen}{)}

\begin{document}

\section{Part 2}

\begin{flushleft}
$(-1.03, 2.87)$ decodes as \bits{0100} \\
$(-3.28, -1.21)$ decodes as \bits{0011} --- together, \bits{01000011} gives ``C''

\bigskip

$(-0.97, -2.71)$ decodes as \bits{0110}\\
$(2.21, -0.95)$ decodes as \bits{1011} --- together, \bits{01101011} gives ``k''\\
\textbf{Probable error} \\
\textbf{Probable intended bit sequence: \bits{01101111} ``o''}

\bigskip

$(-1.37, -1.48)$ decodes as \bits{0111}\\
$(-2.86, -2.51)$ decodes as \bits{0010} --- together, \bits{01110010} gives ``r''

\bigskip

$(-1.37, -2.73)$ decodes as \bits{0110}\\
$(1.22, -3.17)$ decodes as \bits{1110} --- together, \bits{01101110} gives ``n''
\end{flushleft}

\section{Part 2}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  >{\lparen}S[table-space-text-pre=\lparen,table-format=-1.2]
  @{,\,}
  S[table-space-text-post=\rparen,table-format=-1.2]<{\rparen}
  >{\ttfamily}c
  >{\ttfamily}c
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Point} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{decodes as} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{together} &
gives \\
\midrule
-1.03 &  2.87 & 0100 \\
-3.28 & -1.21 & 0011 & 01000011 & C \\
\addlinespace

-0.97 & -2.71 & 0110\\
 2.21 & -0.95 & 1011 & 01101011 & k \\
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\bfseries Probable error} \\
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\bfseries Probable intended bit sequence} & 01101111 & \bfseries o\\
\addlinespace

-1.37 & -1.48 & 0111\\
-2.86 & -2.51 & 0010 & 01110010 & r \\
\addlinespace

-1.37 & -2.73 & 0110\\
 1.22 & -3.17 & 1110 & 01101110 & n \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]